Backmapping problem from martini to charmm36
I have been reverse mapping successfully until a week ago. backward.py is confusing atoms for different residues for another. For example, it confuses atoms for met for ala, some cases, asp for arg. This is derailing my work.
I have checked the itps file for correspondent Claudins which I am working on, but there seems to be no inconsistency.
I would appreciate help.

You used a plural form, so I take it that your protein is multimeric? Try backmapping the protein one monomer at the time. Backward is quite old and tired, so you'll going to have to be gentle with it. If you can't hack it, use CG2AT by Owen Vickery.
